# Adding a date in DIV in PHP

Tags: php, html, date

I'm just starting with PHP and am stuck on something that should be easy to solve.

In this script I'd lik to add an echo/print? of the date that is applicable in the rest of the script at the DATE NEEDED part.

Can someone tell me how I add a div around "DATE NEEDED" and have it show the actual date on the site?

```
if ( get_option('vh_time_format') == false || get_option('vh_time_format') == '24h' ) 
{
    $output .= '<li><div class="time icon-clock">' . $needed_info[0]
             . '</div> DATE NEEDED <div class="ticket hover_right"><a href="'
             . $new_button_link . '" class="icon-ticket">' . $new_button_text 
             . '</a></div><div class="event_auditory">' . __('Venue:', 'vh')
             . $value['theatre'] . ', ' . $needed_info[1] . '</div></li>';
} 
else { (almost the same) }
```

Answer (score 1):

With date function:

```
$output .= '<li><div class="time icon-clock">'.$needed_info[0].'</div> <div>'.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'</div> <div class="ticket hover_right"><a href="'.$new_button_link.'" class="icon-ticket">'.$new_button_text.'</a></div><div class="event_auditory">' . __('Venue:', 'vh') . $value['theatre'].', '.$needed_info[1].'</div></li>';
                                          div start, date, and div end ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: No wait.. It's the date of today, but not the date used elsewhere in the function;

if ( (( $value['date'] == $post_date && $show_all != '1' ) || ( $value['date'] >= $post_date && $show_all == '1' )) ) { etc.

How can I get the date that is used above?

Comment: just create a variable, before the `$output`, and based on your condition, set it, and echos it where you want.